# How to fix a server failure when the client reloads the page?

Tags: javascript, go, websocket

When the client reloads the page, the server issues an error -
websocket: close 1001 (going away).
When the client reloads the page, does not the websocket connection reconnect?
I recently started studying programming, so please forgive if the question is stupid.
Client code

```
var socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/ws" );

socket.onmessage = function (event) {
    DownloadScene(event)
}

function DownloadScene(event) {
    var data = JSON.parse(event.data)
    document.getElementById(data.id).innerHTML = data.body;
}
function  loadScene(scene) {
  var page = {
    query_type:"loadScene",
    data : {temp:scene}
}
   var event = JSON.stringify(page);
   socket.send(event);
}
```

I'm using the gorilla websocket library to build a connection.

Server code

```
func WebSocketHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

   conn, err := upGrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)

   if err != nil {
      log.Println(err)
      return
   }
   for { webSocketHandler(conn)}
   defer conn.Close()
}

func webSocketHandler(conn *websocket.Conn) {

  println("new connect")
  err := conn.ReadJSON(&query)
  if err != nil {
      log.Fatal(err)
      return
  }
  switch query.QueryType {
  case "loadScene" :
    err := json.Unmarshal(query.Data,&frames)
    if err!= nil{
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    var buf  bytes.Buffer
    data := frame.ExecuteTemplate(&buf,"frame",nil)
    if data!=nil{
        log.Fatal(data)
    }
    res,e := json.Marshal(&Frame{"scene",buf.String()})
    if e !=nil{
        log.Println(e)
    }

    errs := conn.WriteMessage(1,res)
    if err!=nil{
        log.Fatal(errs)
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `go`, log.Fatal(..) exits your application.

```
err := conn.ReadJSON(&query)
```

will return an `err` when the client connection closes and the next block:

```
if err != nil {
  log.Fatal(err)
  return
}
```

will close the `go` server and the Javascript client will be unable to reconnect.

Your server structure also doesn't look quite correct - `WebSocketHandler` is invoked to handle a single connection:

```
    .
    http.HandleFunc("/", WebSocketHandler)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe("localhost:8080", nil))
}

func WebSocketHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    conn, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print("Error upgrading websocket:", err)
        return
    }

    defer conn.Close()

    for {
        err = conn.ReadJSON(&query)
        if err != nil {
            log.Print("Error reading query: ", err)
            return
        }
        .
        // -- process query here --
        .
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If on page load websocket connects, then there are no worries. When page refreshes the client will connect to server. you can ignore the exception for websocket close 1001.